# Proving Poisson's Formula for Schwartz Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Show that
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(\frac{n}{a}) = a\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{\phi}(na)$$

I know the solution will basically be using the Dirac Comb, and we have the following

$$\phi *\Delta_a = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(t-na)$$
and
$$\widehat{\phi*\Delta_a} = \hat{\phi} \cdot\hat{\Delta_a} = \hat{\phi} \cdot \frac{1}{a}\Delta_{\frac{1}{a}} = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{\phi} \delta_{\frac{n}{a}} = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{\phi}(\frac{n}{a}) \delta_{\frac{n}{a}}$$
But from these observations, I'm not really sure where to go next.

Comment: You made a mistake in the last line/formula: multiplication, not convolution. Then integrate the Fourier transform over $\Bbb{R}$ it will be $=( \phi\ast \Delta_a) (0)$.

Comment: Still not right.

Comment: how's that now @reuns?

Comment: Now it is right, but $\hat{\phi}(t)\delta(t-b)$ simplifies. Anyway what you need is to equate $( \phi\ast \Delta_a) (0)$ and $\int_\Bbb{R} \frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{\phi}(t)\delta_{\frac{n}{a}}(t)dt$

Comment: Am I correct in thinking $(\phi *\Delta_A)(0) = \sum \phi(-na) = \sum \phi(na)$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{a}\sum \hat{\phi}(t)\delta_{\frac{n}{a}}(t)dt = \frac{1}{a}\sum \hat{\phi}(\frac{n}{a})$?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: In your first comment you said that integrating the Fourier transform over $\mathbb{R}$ will be $(\phi*\Delta_A)(0)$. Why is this the case? I found both of those terms in my previous question and I'm not sure how to show they are equal.

Comment: The Fourier inversion theorem of course

Answer (score 1):

By the way do you like Fourier series? $f(t)=\sum_n \phi(t-na)$ is smooth and $a$-periodic, it is equal to its Fourier series $\sum_k c_k e^{2i\pi kt/a}$ and (for $a >0$) $c_k=a^{-1}\hat{\phi}(n/a)$. Letting $t=0$ gives the Poisson summation formula.

Comment: Isn't this in a sense assuming Poisson's summation formula / what I'm trying to show?

Comment: The Poisson summation formula is just a rephrasing of the theorem that (smooth) functions are equal to their Fourier series.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that
$$(\phi * \Delta_a)(0) = \int_\mathbb{R} \widehat{(\phi * \Delta_a)}(0) dt$$

Next, $$(\phi * \Delta_a)(0) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(na)$$
and
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \widehat{(\phi * \Delta_a)}(0) dt = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{\phi}(\frac{n}{a})$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(na) = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{\phi}(\frac{n}{a})$$
$$\implies \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi(\frac{n}{a}) = a\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\hat{\phi}(na)$$

Comment: @reuns, how is this looking so far? The final answer I have isn't quite the same but it's close.

Comment: Just replace $a$ by $a^{-1}$ to get the first formula of your question